# python 'import' package works in shell but not in Jupyter Notebook. Why?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, virtualenv

I'm trying to import a custom package into my Jupyter Notebook, but I'm have issues. The package works when I open my terminal however I get a 'no module error' when importing the package into my notebook.

I've set up a virtual environment with `python3 -m venv` and used `setuptools` to create a `setup.py` so I can use my custom packages

This is my project structure

```
./-- notebook -- my_notebook.ipynb
  └── src -- funct -- func.py
  └── setup.py
```

I also know I've correctly installed the package:

```
$ pip3 list
Package    Version Location
---------- ------- -------------------------------------------------------
pip        18.0
setuptools 39.0.1
src        0.1.0   /Users/me/project
```

In my terminal:

```
$ python3
>>> import src
>>> from src.funct import func
>>> func.foo()
'Foo'
```

However, when I run `import src` in my notebook, I get:

```
import src
ImportError: No module named src
```

This is my setup.py

```
from setuptools import find_packages, setup

setup(
    name='src',
    packages=find_packages(),
    version='0.1.0',
    description='Example',
    author='me',
    license='MIT',
)
```

If the package can be imported correctly into my python shell, why can't it be imported into my notebook? Is this a permissions issue, and if so how can I check that?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

*** Update ***

Here is the `SOURCES.txt` generated from the `setup.py`

```
README.md
src/__init__.py
src.egg-info/PKG-INFO
src.egg-info/SOURCES.txt
src.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
src.egg-info/top_level.txt
src/funct/__init__.py
src/funct/func.py
```

So now I'm more confused on why it won't import.

Comment: is it to do with where you're running it from? last time I had an issue a bit like this I had to add the folder with the package in to my path by putting `import sys` and `sys.path.append("/Users/me/project")` before the import. Hard coded paths are hacky and you should probably avoid them but it was enough for me.

Comment: Thanks for this :) I did use that previously to make it work, but I'm trying to avoid that hacky solution. I'm trying to move away form notebooks with sys.path.append all over them, just for readability and cleaner code.